# Деактивация QLineEdit при наведении мыши

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мышью на `QLineEdit`, она становилась не активной?
Пытался сделать с помощью `mouseMoveEvent`. Но там нужно нажать сначала и держать, а потом уже наводить. Можно ли сделать, чтобы `mouseMoveEvent` не по щелчку работала?
Вот код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.MW = MainWindow
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(785, 581) # Changed
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, -8, 841, 641))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 231, 541))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.Fon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Fon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 241, 581))
        self.Fon.setText("")
        self.Fon.setObjectName("Fon")
        self.label_categories = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_categories.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label_categories.setObjectName("label_categories")
        self.label_logins = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_logins.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 47, 13))
        self.label_logins.setObjectName("label_logins")
        self.Botton_Create = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Botton_Create.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 10, 71, 21))
        self.Botton_Create.setObjectName("Botton_Create")

        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 60, 47, 13))
        self.label_name.setObjectName("label_name")
        self.Button_Edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_Edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 10, 75, 23))
        self.Button_Edit.setObjectName("Button_Edit")
        self.label_last_modified = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_last_modified.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 450, 47, 13))
        self.label_last_modified.setObjectName("label_last_modified")
        self.Created = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Created.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 480, 47, 13))
        self.Created.setObjectName("Created")
        self.label_time_modif = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_time_modif.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 450, 47, 13))
        self.label_time_modif.setObjectName("label_time_modif")
        self.label_time_created = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_time_created.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 480, 47, 13))
        self.label_time_created.setObjectName("label_time_created")
        self.Website = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Website.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 290, 47, 13))
        self.Website.setObjectName("Website")
        self.Password = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 250, 47, 13))
        self.Password.setObjectName("Password")
        self.Username = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 210, 47, 13))
        self.Username.setObjectName("Username")
        self.label_Username = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_Username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 210, 47, 13))
        self.label_Username.setObjectName("label_Username")
        self.label_Password = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_Password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 250, 47, 13))
        self.label_Password.setObjectName("label_Password")
        self.label_Website = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_Website.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 290, 47, 13))
        self.label_Website.setObjectName("label_Website")

        self.label_image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 60, 71, 61))
        self.label_image.setObjectName("label_image")
        self.label_Favorites = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_Favorites.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label_Favorites.setObjectName("label_Favorites")
        self.label_image_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_image_user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 64, 64))
        self.label_image_user.setObjectName("label_image_user")
        self.label_name_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name_user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 47, 13))
        self.label_name_user.setObjectName("label_name_user")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 40, 3, 600))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.Trans = _translate # Changed
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_categories.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_logins.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Botton_Create.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Button_Edit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label_last_modified.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Created.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_time_modif.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_time_created.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Website.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Password.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.Username.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_Username.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_Password.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_Website.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_image.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_Favorites.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_image_user.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_name_user.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, text=None, wight=200, height=200):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(wight, height)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit{
                           color: black;
                           }""")

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(False)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(True)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        line = CustomLineEdit(text="Какой то текст который был введен")
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка")
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: print(True))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(line)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(300, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

UPD

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import token_ex
import sys


class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, text=None, wight=200, height=200):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(wight, height)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit{
                           color: black;
                           }""")

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(False)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(True)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tok = token_ex.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.tok.setupUi(self)
        self.line_custom = CustomLineEdit(self, "текст")
        self.line_custom.move(200, 400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как настроить enterEvent и leaveEvent на определенную QLineEdit? Ведь они уже созданы в дизайнере, а запускаю я в отдельном файле. Или они отзываются только внутри класса?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov ну вообще это считайте кастомный класс так что я сомневаюсь что можно как то по другому

Comment: Проблемка одна есть. Я создал дизайн. Там нет lineEdit'ов. Создаю другой файл для запуска дизайна. Ну вот незадача не могу отразить созданный через CustomLineEdit на этот дизайн. Designer создает какой-то 'centralwidget' в 'self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)'. Так как мне через кастом поместить  lineEdit в этот виджет?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov киньте код от `designer` в ваш вопрос

Comment: Просто я не знаю как создать именно на моем дизайне.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov ну так у вас на примере все хаотично расположено т.к. не через `layout`

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov обновил ответ где добавляется виджет в ваш файл `designer`, `token_ex` код `designer`

Comment: Я сначала набрасываю примерно виджеты. А потом уже работаю с файлами. layout мне только помешает.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov дело ваше я подправил код чтобы он отображался у вас в коде `designer`

Comment: А что за модуль token_ex? У меня его нет. Попытался через pip установить не вышло.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov `token_ex`  ваш код от `designer`. Мне просто лень новый файл создавать

Comment: А, понятно) А я в pip полез устанавливать))